# JS. Date. Associative array. Как вывести данные корректно?

Tags: javascript, массивы, дата

В программе в поле ввода вводим дату рождения, например 01.01.2000 , жмем на кнопку "показать" , и из массива people с помощью цикла пробегаемся по нему и должно вывести людей, у которых дни рождения попадают на эту дату. Почему то в итоге выводится только 1 человек, либо не вводится ни одного, хотя в массиве есть 2 человека с одинаковой датой рождения, в чем может быть дело?
В консоли все выводится корректно.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Date of birthday</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<header>
<h1>Date of birthday</h1>
</header>
   <div class="">
          <label for="title">Введите дату:</label>
          <input           
            type="date"     
            id="date" >         

        <button 
        class="btn" 
        onclick="dateresult()">
        Показать</button>
        </div>

<hr>
<p>Результат:</p>
   <div id="out"></div>

    <script src="project.js"></script>
</body>
</html>*
```

project.js

```
function dateresult(){

let num1 = document.getElementById('date').value;

const people = [
   {name: 'Vlad', birthday: "2000-03-01"},
    {name: 'Elena', birthday: "2000-05-01"},
   {name: 'Victoria', birthday: "2000-03-01"},
    {name: 'Tom', birthday: "2000-07-01"}
 ]      

for (const person of people) {

  if (person.birthday === num1) {
    let findedPerson = person.name
    console.log(findedPerson) 
    document.getElementById('out').innerHTML=findedPerson       
   } 
   else{       
    document.getElementById('out').innerHTML = "Дней рождений на эту дату нет";
    }   
}

}
```

Comment: потому что выводить строку, что дней рождение нет - нужно после цикла, если их действительно нет, а не на каждой итерации цикла

Answer (score 0):

Вы переменную let findedPerson = person.name переписываете новым значением стирая старое ответ на "Почему то в итоге выводится только 1 человек".

В findedPerson нужно добавлять новую дату на случай если людей с одной датой больше чем один и потом уже записывать в  document.getElementById('out').innerHTML=findedPerson.